# load hdfs file into spark context

Tags: scala, file, hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop2

I am new to spark/scala and need to load a file from hdfs to spark. I have a file in hdfs (`/newhdfs/abc.txt`), and I could see my file contents by using `hdfs dfs -cat /newhdfs/abc.txt`

I did in below order to load the file into spark context

```
spark-shell #It entered into scala console window

scala> import org.apache.spark._; //Line 1
scala> val conf=new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]");
scala> val sc = new SparkContext(conf);
scala> val input=sc.textFile("hdfs:///newhdfs/abc.txt"); //Line 4
```

Once I hit enter on line 4, I am getting below message.

```
input: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = hdfs:///newhdfs/abc.txt MapPartitionsRDD[19] at textFile at <console>:27``
```

Is this a fatal error? What do I need to do to solve this?

(Using Spark-2.0.0 and Hadoop 2.7.0)

Comment: @gsamaras, Noted. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is **not an error**, it just says the name of the file for your RDD.

In the [Basic docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html#basics), there is this example:

```
scala> val textFile = sc.textFile("README.md")
textFile: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = README.md MapPartitionsRDD[1] at textFile at <console>:25
```

which demonstrates the very same behavior.

---

How would you expect an error to happen without an *action* triggering actual work to happen?

If you want to check that everything is OK, do a count of your `input` RDD, which is an action and will trigger the actual read of the file, and then the count of the elements of your RDD.